# NLTK - Location information extraction and identify its owner country

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk, corpus

currently I have a scenario that I want to extract location information in a given text and eventually get the country of the location belong to.

For example:

```
I am studying in New York.
```

I wish to grab the **New York** as a location and find its owner country somehow.

Now I'm using NLTK with Stanford NER package. I can extract the location successfully. And then How can I get its country(using a corpus or something)? I believe I can get it by a geo service. But it's better to achieve without a web service or fixed location table.

Any idea is welcomed! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can train your NER model for geographical data to identify as much as information as you want to.
   But it will have its limitations like spelling variations, place aliases etc.
   This is easily doable with NLTK.
2. There is a NLTK based github project which specializes in geographical NER data : https://github.com/ushahidi/geograpy
   It also supports fuzzy string matches, and things like country lookup.
3. For country lookup, you can either rely on project mentioned in #2, or for more extensive coverage, use [Google places apis](https://developers.google.com/places/) to search for the entity extracted, and select most probable result from the suggestions. The country would be present in its administrative hiearchy provided by Google api results. For example:  San Francisco --> California --> USA